# How to mock or prepare test methods in case we called private method inside the method?

Tags: mockito, junit5, liferay-7, junit-jupiter

While writing a testCase for **Controller** class,The private method that is getServiceContext(). has different object because 
one we are passing serviceContext from **testclass** and other object inside the controller class itself call itself.Due to this Foo object is null. how to resolve this.

public class Controller {

```
@Refernce
private FooService fooService;

public CustomData getDetails(String id){

      Foo foo = fooService.getFoo(id ,**getServiceContext()**); 
         //getServiceContext() is different object
    System.out.println("foo data>>>> "+foo); // **Throwing null pointer exceptions** 

      CustomData customData = new CustomData();
      customData.setStudentName(foo.getName);
      customData.setStudentName(foo.getId);
      ...
      ...
      ...
    return  customData;

}

private ServiceContext getServiceContext() {

 ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    serviceContext.setCompanyId(context..);
    serviceContext.setUserId(context..);
    ...
    ....    
retrn serviceContext;

}
```

}

---

public class ControllerTest {

```
@InjectMocks
private Controller controller;

@Mock
private FooService fooService;

private Foo foo;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws PortalException {

foo = mock(Foo.class);

}

@Test
public void getDetailsTest() throws Exception {

    ServiceContext **serviceContext** = new ServiceContext();
    serviceContext.setCompanyId(context..);
    serviceContext.setUserId(context..);
    ...
    ....    
    Mockito.when(fooService.getFoo("testId",serviceContext)).thenReturn(foo);

    System.out.println("Service context>>>> "+**serviceContext**); // different serviceContext object
    CustomData customData = controller.getDetails("testId");

    Assertions.assertThat(ss).isNotNull();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

First, we can mock with `anyOf(Type.class)`, that will actually match object type rather than value.

```
Mockito
 .when(fooService.getFoo(Mockit.eq("testId"), Mockito.any(ServiceContext.class)))
 .thenReturn(foo);
```

this will work as expected and return the desired value.

Additionally, if you want to check with what data `serviceContext` object is being passed as arg in service method, (as we just checked object type rather than value), We can use `ArgumentCaptor` for that.

It basically captures argument data which is being passed in the method call.

let's create ArgumentCaptor for service context

```
@Mock
private FooService fooService;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<ServiceContext> captor;
```

Now, let's capture the argument during verification.

```
Mockito.verify(fooService).getFoo(Mockit.eq("testId"), captor.capture());

Assertions.assertEquals("value of x in context", captor.getValue().getX());
```

Basically here, `captor.getValue()` returns service context object which is being passed. So, you can verify all data you want to validate in that object.

**Alternate**, Approach would be `Spy` which will basically spy on the class under test and you can control the behavior of private methods in test class itself.

To do that, we need to add `@Spy` annotation along with `@InjectMocks` on test class.

```
@Spy
@InjectMocks
private Controller controller;
```

Now, you can mock the private method and return the expected value.

```
Mockito.doReturn(serviceContextValue).when(controller).getServiceContext();
```

and use that object for mocking `fooService`.

```
Mockito.verify(fooService).getFoo("testId", serviceContextValue);
```

But when using `Spy`, don't forget to write unit test for private method as it's mocked, it's business logic will not be tested by above test cases. that's a reason, it's not recommended way.

I would suggest using `ArgumentCaptor` approach.